# Change Color of Waveform Plot Using Time Values

Tags: matlab, speech

I am currently working on a Speech Processing project and had a quick question regarding a time waveform for a word in Spanish (aire).

[image: Aire]

I want to highlight the portion of the waveform that contains the phoneme **ai**. Using Audacity, I have been able to mark the locations in time where the phoneme occurs and wanted to know how I could possibly change the color of just that part of the waveform.

I have been told to use the `hold on` function in MatLab but am not sure as to which parameters I should be passing in or if there are easier ways of accomplishing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution using `hold on`:

```
% something to plot:
x = 1:1000;
y = sin(linspace(-pi,pi,1000)*10).^3;
% the region of interest:
ai_start = find(x>200);
ai_end = find(x>400);
% plotting:
plot(x(1:ai_start-1),y(1:ai_start-1)); % first part
hold on
plot(x(ai_start:ai_end),y(ai_start:ai_end),'r')% the ai region
plot(x(ai_end+1:end),y(ai_end+1:end),'Color',lines(1))% end part
hold off
```

[image: colored line]

Comment: Any idea how I could do the same with values that are not integers for `ai_start` and `ai_end`? For example, I am currently getting the following: `Warning: Integer operands are required for colon operator when used as index`

Comment: @User5842 assuming you can find the specific index on `x`, just use `find`. I have edited the answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.